# TextMate bundle to insert a line of text above each line selected?

Tags: linux, string, text, textmate, textmatebundles

I'm looking for a way to insert a line of text above each line in the selected text in TextMate.

Does anyone know how to write a command or snippet to do this?

**Example, selected text:**

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
This is line 4
```

**I want to insert the following above each line selected:**

--im an inserted line--

**Which would result in the following:**

-

```
-im an inserted line--
This is line 1
--im an inserted line--
This is line 2
--im an inserted line--
This is line 3
--im an inserted line--
This is line 4
```

Could this be done using *NIX commands then I could setup a TextMate command to do this?

Comment: Would love to know why this question has been flagged as off topic? My question was relating to TextMate bundle programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your text, press APPLE + F, then replace `\n` with `\n--Im an inserted line--\n`. Make sure that 'Regular expression' is ticked and that you hold in SHIFT while pressing the 'Replace All' button.

Comment: Perfect! That was by far the easiest answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would record a macro:

1. Insert a new line above with <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↩</kbd>
2. Paste desired text

Then save it as a command and possibly assign a shortcut to it.

EDIT

The best way to achive what you want in TextMate is to select all the lines then hit <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> (*Text* > *Edit Each Line in Selection*) then do all the keyboard mashing necessary to paste what you want where you want:

1. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> to go back to the beginning of the line
2. <kbd>↩</kbd> to insert a newline, effectively adding a blank line above the current line
3. <kbd>↑</kbd> to jump to the new blank line
4. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to paste your text

It will do that on each selected line simultaneously.

You can save a few keystrokes the next time you have to do that by recording all these steps in a macro and save it as a command as in the first part of my answer.

Comment: I need this to insert the same line of text above every line on selected text. I have 1000's of lines selected and it would take too long to do manually.

Comment: To be honest, that's the kind of thing that made me move to Vim.

Comment: I'm a bit scared by Vim. I know TextMate can do it I'm just not sure how to make it do it!

Comment: See my edit, it will solve your problem. I was scared/attracted by Vim until I found myself with nothing to do for a week. I tried it seriously (`$ vimtutor`) and now I don't see myself going back to TextMate.

Answer (score 0):

**To insert line above current line**

I believe the key shortcut is: <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>↩</kbd>

Comment: @Camsoft insert blank line above current line.

Comment: @Camsoft, scroll down a little and you'll see it here: http://projects.serenity.de/textmate/tutorials/basics/#commonbundleshortcuts

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was being clear. I was not trying to insert a blank line but needed a TextMate command or snippet to insert a line of text above each selected line.

Comment: @Camsoft in that case your probably going to need to create a bundle snippet. This isn't something that I've done before, but the following may help you: http://manual.macromates.com/en/snippets  Looks like you'll need an understanding of objective-c to do this.

Comment: Yeah I was aware of that, that was why I asked the orignal question. ;-) Thanks anyway.